# Flutter IsarDB getting NULL in nested relationship

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-isar

I have a collection named 'user' in Isar:

```dart
@Collection()
class UserCollection {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  @Index()
  late String mobileNumber;

  String? name = '';
  final profile = IsarLink<ProfileCollection>();
}
```

It is linked to another collection named 'profile':

```dart
@Collection()
class ProfileCollection {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  final IsarLinks<FavoritesMenuCollection> favoriteMenus = IsarLinks<FavoritesMenuCollection>();
  @Backlink(to: 'profile')
  final user = IsarLink<UserCollection>();
}
```

And the 'profile' collection itself is connected as a `@Backlink` to another collection named 'favoriteMenus':

```dart
@Collection()
class FavoritesMenuCollection {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  @Backlink(to: 'favoriteMenus')
  final profile = IsarLink<ProfileCollection>();
}
```

I don't have any issues linking 'profile' to 'user', but when I link the 'favoriteMenus' collection to 'profile', the 'profile' property in the 'FavoritesMenuCollection' gets stored as null, and the link is not created. Here's the code I've implemented:

```dart
final profile = ProfileCollection()
  ..favoriteMenus.addAll(favoriteMenus);

await isar.isarInstance.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.isarInstance.favoritesMenuCollections.putAll(favoriteMenus);
      await isar.isarInstance.profileCollections.put(profile);
});

final user = isar.findLast<UserCollection>()!;

 await isar.isarInstance.writeTxn(() async {
   user
     ..profile.value = profile
     ..active = res.user!.active
     ..verified = true;
   await user.profile.save();
 });
```

What could be causing the 'profile' property in 'FavoritesMenuCollection' to be null when linking the collections?

Answer (score 1):

In order to link `FavoritesMenuCollection`s to your `ProfileCollection` you need to call `save()`.
Add

```dart
await profile.favoriteMenus.save();
```

to the bottom of your first `writeTxn()` to fix it.

See [IsarLinks](https://isar.dev/links.html#isarlinks) documentation